# Opening DIV closes others

Tags: javascript, css, prototypejs

Having a little problem, I have a module that is a filtered left nav for filtering products on an ecommerce site.

```
     function amshopby_filter_show(evt) {
  var dt = Event.findElement(evt, 'dt');

  dt.next('dd').down('ol').toggle();
  dt.toggleClassName('amshopby-collapsed');

  Event.stop(evt);
  return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Tn3D/6/

I need DROPDOWN1 to toggle the 'ol' so that it opens and closes, but I also need to only have one DROPDOWN open at a time. So if you then opened up DROPDOWN2, it would open DROPDOWN2 but also close DROPDOWN1.

Really hopes this makes sense, and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks guys.

Mike

Comment: That's Prototype code, not jQuery.

Comment: use accordian plugin.

Comment: thanks @lonesomeday, I have updated jsfiddle to Prototype, still no luck. :(

Comment: I can point you in a direction - `siblings()` will return all of the siblings of a specific element except for the target element and you can operate on the siblings.

Answer (score 0):

I've always closed/hidden all dropdowns and *then* opened the single new dropdown.

Comment: from a usability point of view, we cant do this as we have lots of options under each dropdown and on mobile devices it becomes a problem.